Is there a way to speed up Firebird ADO.net provider?
Is there a way to speed up Firebird ADO.net provider?
VS 2022, .NET8:, Console App, FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient 10.0.0
using FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;

Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);

var csb = new FbConnectionStringBuilder();
csb.Database = ...;
csb.DataSource = ...;
csb.Dialect = 1;
csb.Charset = "WIN1250";
csb.Pooling = true;
csb.Port = 3050;
csb.IsolationLevel = System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
csb.UserID = ...;
csb.Password = ...;

using(var connection = new FbConnection(csb.ConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    var cmd = new FbCommand("SELECT ID FROM SOMETABLE", connection);
    using(var r = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        int cnt = 0;
        var s = new Stopwatch();
        s.Start();
        while(r.Read())
        {
            cnt++;
        }
        s.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"{cnt} in {s.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
    }
}

results:
69790 in 365ms
69790 in 380ms
69790 in 355ms
...

Delphi 5, IBX, Form Application, InterbaseExpress 5.0.4
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var cnt : Integer;
    c : DWord;
begin
  IBDatabase1.Open;
  IBTransaction1.StartTransaction;
  IBSQL1.ExecQuery;
  cnt := 0;
  c := timeGetTime;
  While not IBSQL1.Eof do
    Begin
      cnt := cnt + 1;
      IBSQL1.Next;
    End;
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(cnt) + ' in ' + IntToStr(timeGetTime - c) + 'ms');
  IBSQL1.Close;
  IBTransaction1.Commit;
  IBDatabase1.Close;
end;

results:
69790 in 168ms
69790 in 183ms
69790 in 169ms

The same database (accessed via LAN), the same computer, multiple tests => .Net is more than two times slower.
EDIT:
According to https://stackoverflow.com/users/30568/mghie sugestions:
csb.PacketSize: default 8192
Lower value: 1024 => > 60000ms
Max value: 32767 => ~390ms

csb.FetchSize: default 200
Lower value: 100 => ~600ms
Higher value: 1000-1500 => ~200ms!
Higher values: 2000+ => ~250ms+

Is there some kind of optimal FetchSize value ?

Firebird 2.5.9 x64 on Windows

Maybe the benefit of using a native compiling language vs. an intermediate language! ;-)

Delphi 5 DOB = 1999; VS 2022 DOB = 2024; So 25 years later ... where are we going ...  (:

Try setting csb.FetchSize to something like 1000 (best value depends on your average record size), and increasing csb.PacketSize (may improve things depending on your network latency). Also use a transaction to compare apples with similar fruit.

More likely it has to do with the fact that Delphi uses the native library, fbclient.dll, while the Firebird ADO.net provider is a reimplementation of the wire protocol in .NET, and thus might do things differently than the native client. Recent versions of fbclient.dll for example do async fetching (requesting a new block of rows while it still has rows pending, and receive the response asynchronously), which I'm not sure the Firebird ADO.net provider does. They may also use different fetch sizes.

Note that I removed the [tag:delphi] tag, because your question is not about Delphi, you're merely comparing to Delphi, but you want to fix a problem in .NET.

How do you run your console app? Is there any chance that you are running in the debug mode?

Yes, i was running it from VS in Debug profile. Changed to Release x86, running from cmd - results are almost the same (running from cmd gives me more stable results). With FetchSize = 2000, results are about 180ms. It is quite close to Delphi app now - 170ms (I testes now both projects Delphi and C#). It is less than 10% now. I think the key issue was FetchSize. But I'm not sure how will it work with different query structure (more cols / rows). I will try prepare tests.

I've changed SQL to:
SELECT ID, NAME FROM SOMETABLE

where NAME is VARCHAR(250) col, and result differs stable about 10%:
Delphi 390ms
C# (release, fs=2000) 430ms

@b0bik "results are almost the same" - a bit surprised by that TBH =) Several notes - this is not a way to benchmark stuff in .NET (or possibly almost any other language) unless it is your actual usecase - "one time executing" console application (in this case I highly recommend to look at Native AOT or at least ReadyToRun), in other cases if you want to benchmark something in .NET you should look into using appropriate tooling.

.NET app at start will load needed assemblies and compile some code from IL at the first usage (and maybe recompile with more optimizations) which is not that noticable for long-running server-side app but can have negative effect for console ones.

P.S. "VS 2022 DOB = 2024" - VS is IDE, multilanguage IDE, it's DOB has not that much to do with performance of the build app =)
